# Why c# is decoded in js in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Sorry guys, my english is not so good, so please try to understand.

Here is the code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var str = "http://example.com?a=1&b=2";
}

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                console.log('@str');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My expectation is `http://example.com?a=1&b=2`, but in console, the result is `http://example.com?a=1&amp;b=2`.

Please explain to me, thanks.

Comment: i not see any different?

Comment: Is that string encoded? I don't see any difference between those results. If my guess right, use `@Html.Raw(str)`.

Comment: @panshu your expectation and current output in the question is same! with the code you posted, the current output will be `http://example.com?a=1&amp;b=2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the encoded version

```
http://example.com?a=1&amp;b=2
```

Because in razor, when you use `@` prefix, razor does HTML encoding before rendering the result of executing the following expression. Hence you are seeing `@` changed to `&amp;`

If you do not want this to happen, You can use `Html.Raw` method which does not do the encoding

```
console.log('@Html.Raw(str)');
```

This will render

```
http://example.com?a=1&b=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure how that url is not generated from user input, then only use `Html.Raw`. Further, you can use `Url.RouteUrl` to generate url first.

```
@{
    string str = Url.RouteUrl("", new RouteValueDictionary(new { a = 9, b = 2}), "https", "example.com");   
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
         console.log('@Html.Raw(str)');
    });
</script>
```